# Objective C Member reference base type error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm following the code from the Learning iOS Programming 2nd Edition book by Alasdair Allan page 91. I'm trying to make a table view output information to the text view. Everything else works before I add this code. The delegate.cities refers to a NSMutableArray called cities in the AppDelegate.

I think is might have something to do with *objectAtIndex* expecting a *NSUInteger*, but the book says to send it *index.row*. *index* is of type *NSIndexPath* which is in my SimpleView class which I imported into this class. *row* is of type *NSInteger* so I'm assuming that the problem is that the book wants me to send  *objectAtIndex* a signed integer when it is expecting an unsigned integer. Could that be he problem? If so, how do I fix it?

Error message:
Member reference base type 'char *(const char*,int)' is not a structure or union

Here's my function:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppDelegate *delegate = 
            (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    City *thisCity = [delegate.cities objectAtIndex:index.row]; //error with index.row

    self.title = thisCity.cityName;
}
```

Comment: Integer conversion occurs automagically. It's irrelevant/unrelated. I'm sure you use `NSIndexPath index` instead of `NSIndexPath *index`.

Answer (score 2):

The global function `index()` in the system header `string.h` is defined with a signature similar to that of the error (`char* (const char*, int)`).  It appears that the compiler thinks you are trying to access *that function* as a structure or union (i.e. by using `.row` on it, which is something you could do to a structure).

Apparently there is either no field named `index` in your class (you haven't shown the class so I'm guessing), or the compiler is somehow resolving it incorrectly.  Either use the correct field name or disambiguate it by using something like `self->index.row`.